# Low intraclass correlation although between variance is very high in random effects model

Tags: regression, logistic, random-effects-model, intraclass-correlation

I don't understand why a random effects model can give you a very low `rho` (intraclass correlation coefficient), if the between variance (between subjects) in your dataset is very high on all independent variables compared to the within variance (over time). Maybe my interpretation of `rho` is incorrect and somebody can help me understand it correctly.

As you can see from this table, between variane is much higher than within variance for almost all independent variables:

```
. xtsum IV_1-IV_10

Variable         |      Mean   Std. Dev.       Min        Max |    Observations
-----------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------
IV_1     overall |  9703.536   92324.06          0    3551455 |     N =  128238
         between |               105455          0    3509721 |     n =    2497
         within  |             2094.317  -226060.1   131299.5 | T-bar = 51.3568
                 |                                            |
IV_2     overall |  725.3808   3339.206          0   106827.5 |     N =  128238
         between |             3769.248          0     106817 |     n =    2497
         within  |             71.34145  -2631.032   13295.87 | T-bar = 51.3568
                 |                                            |
IV_3     overall |  960.2351   574.6654   .0028935   2656.622 |     N =  128238
         between |             614.7887   .4450117   2635.694 |     n =    2497
         within  |             69.42291   714.5346    1170.56 | T-bar = 51.3568
                 |                                            |
IV_4     overall |  .0446572   .2065295          0          1 |     N =  128238
         between |             .2076612          0          1 |     n =    2497
         within  |             .0183641  -.9040607   .9840511 | T-bar = 51.3568
                 |                                            |
IV_5     overall |  .5832515   .4930224          0          1 |     N =  128238
         between |              .498173          0          1 |     n =    2497
         within  |                    0   .5832515   .5832515 | T-bar = 51.3568
                 |                                            |
IV_6     overall |  .8897909   .3131515          0          1 |     N =  128238
         between |             .3459811          0          1 |     n =    2497
         within  |                    0   .8897909   .8897909 | T-bar = 51.3568
                 |                                            |
IV_7     overall |    .70823   .4545788          0          1 |     N =  128238
         between |             .4657856          0          1 |     n =    2497
         within  |                    0     .70823     .70823 | T-bar = 51.3568
                 |                                            |
IV_8     overall |  .1469527   .3092312          0          1 |     N =  128238
         between |             .2002412          0          1 |     n =    2497
         within  |             .2398179  -.8360982   1.137862 | T-bar = 51.3568
                 |                                            |
IV_9     overall |  5.341053   15.03976          1        453 |     N =  128238
         between |             17.59767          1   308.2857 |     n =    2497
         within  |             7.586072  -242.5589   329.5824 | T-bar = 51.3568
                 |                                            |
IV_10    overall |  13.00411   35.60811          0       2230 |     N =  128238
         between |             27.50115          0        279 |     n =    2497
         within  |             30.47548  -265.9959   2098.004 | T-bar = 51.3568

       etc
```

For my in dependent variable, I get:

```
. xtsum DV

Variable         |      Mean   Std. Dev.       Min        Max |    Observations
-----------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------
DV       overall |  .3408194   .4739866          0          1 |     N =  128238
         between |             .1320563   .0191388   .8740157 |     n =    2497
         within  |             .4584589  -.5331963   1.321681 | T-bar = 51.3568
```

My model output however states a `rho` of 0.0407. Please correct me if that's wrong but this means that the share of between-variance on the total variance in this model is ~4% .

```
.xtlogit DV IV_1-IV_10, re    

Random-effects logistic regression              Number of obs      =    128238
Group variable: nameID                          Number of groups   =      2497

Random effects u_i ~ Gaussian                   Obs per group: min =         2
                                                               avg =      51.4
                                                               max =       209

                                                Wald chi2(21)      =   9381.54
Log likelihood  =  -75336.99                    Prob > chi2        =    0.0000

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             DV      |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        IV_1         |  -9.35e-08   1.15e-07    -0.81   0.418    -3.20e-07    1.33e-07
        IV_2         |   2.33e-07   2.86e-06     0.08   0.935    -5.37e-06    5.84e-06
        IV_3         |  -.0000156   .0000191    -0.82   0.413     -.000053    .0000218
        IV_4         |   .0249436   .0546815     0.46   0.648    -.0822301    .1321173
        IV_5         |  -.0384232   .0237309    -1.62   0.105     -.084935    .0080885
        IV_6         |    .089663    .036282     2.47   0.013     .0185516    .1607743
        IV_7         |  -.0131013   .0255441    -0.51   0.608    -.0631668    .0369641
        IV_8         |   -.231409   .0253735    -9.12   0.000    -.2811401   -.1816779
        IV_9         |   .0073497   .0006319    11.63   0.000     .0061112    .0085882
       IV_10         |  -.0000409   .0002392    -0.17   0.864    -.0005096    .0004279
               _cons |  -1.924186   .0481483   -39.96   0.000    -2.018555   -1.829817
---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
            /lnsig2u |   -1.96814    .054337                     -2.074639   -1.861641
---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
             sigma_u |   .3737867   .0101552                      .3544034      .39423
                 rho |   .0407386   .0021234                      .0367744    .0451101
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Likelihood-ratio test of rho=0: chibar2(01) =  1534.08 Prob >= chibar2 = 0.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative size of between-cluster variance vs. within-cluster variance on your *independent variables* is *totally irrelevant* for the intra-class correlation. You only need to consider the variance of your dependent variable. And you can see that for your dependent variable, there is far more within-cluster variance than between-cluster variance, consistent with a low intra-class correlation. So there is no contradiction here.